# Bash command - name an column I created that currently is populated without a column name

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Sorry that this is probably really basic, but I have created the below command that accomplishes my initial goal of adding a column and returning "1" or "0" based on whether a condition is met.

That said, the column currently is returned w/o any name. Is there an easy way to notate what the returned column name should be?

`awk -F, 'NR>1 {$0 = $0 FS (($2 >= 1 && $2<=20) ? 1 : 0)} 1' updatedDataset.csv > testdata2.csv`

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @shawn - I tried your recommendation but couldn't get it to work. 
@Nic3500 - Here's an example - if doc is named example.csv: 

``col1,col2
a,2
b,8
c,50
d,4``

``awk -F, 'NR>1 {$0=$0 FS (($2 >= 1 && $2 <= 20) ? 1:0)}1' example.csv``

the command on example.csv returns

``col1,col2
a,2,1
a,8,1
a,50,0
a,4,1
a,2,1``

but I want it to return

``col1,col2,col3
a,2,1
a,8,1
a,50,0
a,4,1
a,2,1``

i.e., what i'm looking for is the "col3" to be added

Answer (score 0):

-- Update: Figured it out. Here's the correct script

`awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="col3"} NR>1 {$0 = $0 FS (($2 >= 1 && $2<=20) ? 1 : 0)} 1' example.csv`

I'm sure there was a better way to do this, but this seems to work fine so far.